# XPath with text() to get specific text node

Tags: atata

[image: Console screenshot][image]

```html
<td style="width: 40.42%;" id="ember193" class="lt-cell align-left ember-view">
    <div class="inline-block ember-tooltip-target">
      <i class="fa fa-fw fa-lg valid"></i>
        <div id="ember195" class="ember-tooltip-base ember-view">  
      <div><!----></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#" data-ember-action="" data-ember-action-196="196">UNIVERSITY OF VERMONT AND STATE AGRICULTURAL COLLEGE</a>
    (03-0179440)<!----><br>
    <div class="fa fa-fw fa-lg"></div>
    (UNIVERSITY OF VERMONT)
</td>
```

In the browser console, I execute this:

```
$x("//tbody/tr[2]/td[2]/text()[7]")
```

and I get the actual text node I am looking for (amongst other text nodes in td[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GUkbk.png)) - is there a way to specify this in a Text<_> property attribute to get just this text node?

Comment: Could you please share the HTML of that `<td>` element?

Comment: Inline with question - thanks!

Comment: Thanks. So you are looking for "(UNIVERSITY OF VERMONT)" text, right?

Comment: Actually 03-0179440

Comment: Also - this returns null: [GetsContentFromSource(ContentSource.LastChildTextNode)]

Comment: Thanks for pointing about `null`. In next Atata version I will update that functionality to skip text nodes that are empty or whitespace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, there is no attribute to get a value of child text node by index, only first or last. Anyway, I would try not to rely on child node index as it can vary. I would try to extract the number part from the given text.

You can do it with a help of 2 properties:

```
[FindByXPath("td")] // TODO: Change it to your <td> locator.
[GetsContentFromSource(ContentSource.ChildTextNodesTrimmed)]
private Text<_> OrganizationNameInfo { get; set; }

public DataProvider<string, _> OrganizationNumber => GetOrCreateDataProvider(
    "Organization Number",
    () =>
    {
        string organizationNameInfo = OrganizationNameInfo.Value;
        return organizationNameInfo.Substring(1, organizationNameInfo.IndexOf(')') - 1);
    });
```

`OrganizationNameInfo` property because of `ContentSource.ChildTextNodesTrimmed` returns `"(03-0179440)(UNIVERSITY OF VERMONT)"` value. So in `OrganizationNumber` property you can easily extract as a sub-string the part you need.

Another option can be to use Regex to extract the number part.

Comment: Thanks for the knowledge - This is the piece I've been missing - how to use the DataProvider - you got the ball rolling... any idea why in my case the [GetsContentFromSource(ContentSource.LastChildTextNode)] returns null?

Comment: You are welcome. That last text node actually contains only spaces. And Atata does `trim` of the value, which leads to empty string, and then it is converted to null. I will have to update this part in Atata to skip whitespace text nodes.